# Copiar arquivo cate e ls

Tags: linux

Qual outro comando faz copia do que esta dentro do arquivo em `<>` para o outro arquivo.
`cat < file1.txt > file2.txt` - Há alguma comando que faça isto com pipe?

E tambem `ls –lsR | more` há algum comando que faça isto sem utilizar o pipe ?

Seria o `ls -ls`?

Pelo o que eu entendi `ls -lsr`, retorna as permissões junto com a quantidade de arquivos dentro da pasta.

E o `ls -lsr | more` retorna as permissões dos arquivos, igual `ls -ls`

Comment: É mais fácil você [edit] a pergunta especificar o problema que quer resolver de fato. Assim está muito confusa, e misturando assuntos. **O comando para copiar arquivos é o `cp`**

Comment: Beleza, irei corrigir.

Comment: Só tome cuidado de nao mudar muito o sentido e estragar a resposta existente. Talvez, agora que tem resposta, compense deixar como está

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primeiramente o comando `cat` não serve para fazer cópia de arquivo, sua real funcionalidade é mostrar o conteúdo dos arquivos, caso queira usá-lo para criar cópias de arquivos o correto é `cat arquivo.txt > copia.txt`, o comando que faz a cópia dos arquivos é o `cp`, e para usar: `cp arquivo.txt copia.txt`.

Já em relação ao `ls`, o ls serve apenas para listar os diretórios e arquivos, ele não possui funções de paginação, para fazer a paginação dos diretórios, só utilizando o pipe junto do comando de paginação, `more`, `less`,...

Mas é possível juntar esses 2 comando em um usando `alias` (apelidos), do seguinte modo:

```
$ cd
# vim é um editor de texto assim como o nano, joe, gedit, pluma, etc
$ vim .profile
```

.profile:

```
#!/bin/bash

alias lsm='ls -lsr | more'
```

Após salvar o arquivo, faça logout para atualizar as informações e sempre que chamar o comando `lsm`, automaticamente o shell vai chamar o `ls -lsr | more`

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, desculpe so me espressei errado na questão do cat.
5) Que outro comando faz o mesmo que cat < file1.txt > file2.txt?
A questão é essa.

Obrigado pelo retorno, esclareceu bastante.

Comment: @BrenoSobral ele respondeu isso no primeiro parágrafo: "o comando que faz a cópia dos arquivos é o cp, e para usar: `cp arquivo.txt copia.txt`"